# using button to switch the input panel and input preview panel in the same activity in android

Tags: android

I aims to click the button to switch the input panel and input preview panel in the same activity so i am doing sth like that:

In one activity,there are one EditText,one button with the text value 'preview' and one textView. Initially, the visibility of editText and button is visible, the textview is set gone value. When the button is clicked,it gets the input value from the editText and set the value to textview. Also, the visibility of editText is set gone and textview is set visible.Finally, the text of button change to 'edit'.

To do this, I have written some code like that:

```
 public void showNewsPreview(){
    txtContentPreview.setText(edtContent.getText());
    edtContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtContentPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnPreview.setText("Edit"); 
}
```

As a result,the code has been run successfully but the view dose not change.
whether i was missed something or the workflow has problem?

Answer (score 0):

Slight change:

```
 public void showNewsPreview(){
    txtContentPreview.setText(edtContent.getText().toString());
    edtContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtContentPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnPreview.setText("Edit"); 
 }
```

Comment: the problem is the editText does not change to gone and textview does not change to visible

Comment: What layout are your using?